# Flutter Print on Android Built In Printer

Tags: android, flutter, printing, aidl, thermal-printer

May i ask help to use flutter for print in my android built in printer ?
I already search in everywhere but not found a clue but i just try use sunmi pos reference but still failed to print.

Thank You

Comment: For built-in printers, the vendor's SDK will be available. Flutter may not be supported, but is it basic information for adapting existing libraries?

Comment: Thank You for your reply but i am already asked SDK from vendor but he tell me he didn't provide any SDK. Is there any a way to detect attach printer in android phone ? @kunif

Comment: At least no one can do anything without a manual? Searching only shows cloud print and network/wireless printers. There is another example of a printer connected by USB OTG, but the software for it is provided by the vendor. [HP Printers - Printing With a USB OTG Cable (Android)](https://support.hp.com/sk-en/document/c05384190)

Comment: yes,that's the problem.i got manual instrution from box but just how to use instruction. I already searching but just show like you searching. Thank You for the help @kunif. I will try that link..

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there are packages that you can use for this functionality. Check the following:

- [blue_thermal_printer](https://pub.dev/packages/blue_thermal_printer)
- [bluetooth_thermal_printer](https://pub.dev/packages/bluetooth_thermal_printer)
- [bluetooth_print](https://pub.dev/packages/bluetooth_print)
- [esc_pos_utils](https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_utils)
- [flutter_sunmi_printer](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sunmi_printer)

As mentioned in your post that you've tried to use sunmi pos reference. Try to explore the specific package for it. Also, I suggest to try the more popular package such as **esc_pos_bluetooth**. Here are some reference with steps on how you can implement it.

- [Printing in Flutter via thermal bleutooth printer](https://medium.com/flutter-community/printing-in-flutter-via-thermal-bleutooth-printer-85d06751a149)
- [Flutter: Adding Thermal Printer](https://medium.com/smartters-studio/flutter-adding-thermal-printer-b27e1740a836)